# has_many :through and getting associated items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This is a follow-up to this question [has_many :through usage, simple, beginner question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524528/has-many-through-usage-simple-beginner-question)

Basically, I'd like to have a function in my Invoice class that gets all the LineItems but the following is not working:

so:

```
> @i=Invoice.find(1)      # good   
> @i.products             # good works well  
> @i.products.line_items  # not working, undefined method line_items
```

based upon associations in previous question, should this be working? I think it should if I access products directly:

```
> @p=Product.find(1)      # good  
> @p.line_items           # also good
```

How can I get back all the line items based upon this model?

thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [has_many :through usage, simple, beginner question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524528/has-many-through-usage-simple-beginner-question)

Comment: `has_many :through` allows you to get all model objects that are indirectly accessible from **one** model object, not by **all** model objects. So no, it is not supposed to work.

Comment: See my answer to your first question: I don't think this question makes sense in light of that. Once you fix things up, feel free to re-ask this, there is something called ["association methods"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529606/how-do-rails-association-methods-work) that you can use to select collections within collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have following models:

```
class Invoice
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, :through => :line_items
end

class LineItems
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :invoices, :through => :line_items
end
```

You can do the following:

> @i=Invoice.find(1)      # good
>   @i.products             # good works well
>   @i.line_items           # all the line_items associated with the invoice.

Comment: is this making the LineItems the class between Product and Invoice. What I'm trying to model is kinda screwy where each product is unique so that a 'LineItem' is really a 'Cost' for internal accounting. I only ask because most of the exaamples I've seen have used the class with two belongs_to as the joining class. thx

Answer (score 1):

`@i.products` returns a collection of `Product`s. You need to collect all the line items:

```
    @i.products.collect(&:line_items)
```

Comment: this should be @i.products.sum([], &:line_items)

Comment: this would give you an array of arrays, better do:
@i.products.sum([], &:line_items)

Comment: Or: `@i.products.collect(&:line_items).flatten`